# jQuery and form: detecting when select drop own has focus

Tags: jquery, forms

If I have set of elements like so:

```
$('table input, table select').focus( function(){})
```

... how can I tell if it's a input or a select that has focus?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) to inspect the type of the element that has been clicked -

```
$('table input, table select').focus( function(event){
 if ($(event.target).attr("type") === 'text') {
 }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/vJPr3/

**EDIT**

Clearer example without the use of event.target -

```
$('input, select').focus(function(){
    if($(this)[0].tagName === 'SELECT') alert('select');
    if($(this).attr("type") === 'text') alert('text');      
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/vJPr3/1/

Comment: ... very cool, but, what's the advantage of $(event.target) over $(this) in this situation?

Comment: ... when I alert type attribute of the 'select' element I get 'select-one' so here's my check: if( $(this).attr("type") === 'select-one')

Comment: That's an excellent point - $(this) would work just as well in your example. I'll update the answer.